# Wi-Fi Module communication?

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, tcpip

I bought a Arduino Wi-Fi Module it does not have any manual or catalog

my project is to turn on/off a motor wireless 
[image]
 it is working grate for the serial/usb cable but i couldn't make it work for wireless/wifi

after some walking around i found that my wifi module is making a wifi network called "HL-link_A49D"
with password from 1-8 and after network scanning i found that the module ip is 192.168.16.254/ username and pass are admin/admin
here is what i found

[image]

my question is how could i connect to the wifi module and send commands to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good detective work so far!
In the admin page you found one can see the name of the module: `HLK-RM04`. Googling on that I found the [manufacturer/seller page](http://www.hlktech.net/product_detail.php?ProId=39).

A PDF with some information can be found [here](http://www.hlktech.net/inc/lib/download/download.php?DId=21).

Also one link with [somebody's experience](http://rayshobby.net/first-impression-on-hlk-rm04-serial-to-wifi-module/) with the module.

For other projects you might want to try as well the ESP8266 - very cheap and seems a lot of people have experience with it, so you might find more information on the net.